# Chemfig ans ACS style

Tags: chemfig

Hellos, someone can help me? I need draw with chemfig but I need ACS style, I found this:

```
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setatomsep{14.4pt}
\setdoublesep{2.6pt}
\setbondstyle{line width=0.6pt}
\setcrambond{2.0pt}{0.6pt}{2.5pt}
\setbondoffset{1.6pt}
\setarrowdefault{,1.0,}
\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\small\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}
```

I don't understand, why not is correct in my text? this is error in my text. I need draw chemicals structures with ACS style. Thanks for help me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This behaviour is due to an older version of  `chemfig` which has changed in the `v1.3 (2018/03/08)` release. Where possible, you should [update your TeX
distribution](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437) to install the
current release. If this is not possible, you will need to [install the
package locally](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137).  This option should be considered a last resort, since there may be package dependencies that will make local installation more complicated and error-prone.

Comment: Hello Alessandro, I have Chemfig 1.41 version. I actualized my Tex Live but  there is  some problem with chemfig. Can you help me with the code for chemfig I need to do draw  for my thesis.

Comment: my version in Tex Live is 2019

Comment: Juliana, if you are sure that you have properly updated your LaTeX system, and that the answer below is not enough, feel free to open a new question. Be sure to read [How to Ask](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) in advance: a  [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) is far better than screenshots.

Answer (score 5):

`chemfig` removed all these commands like `\setatomsep` and `\setbondstyle` in favor of one `\setchemfig` command almost to the day two years ago, in v1.3 (2018/03/08).

```
\setchemfig{
  atom sep=14.4pt,
  double bond sep=2.6pt,
  bond style={line width=0.6pt},
  cram width=2.0pt,
  ...
}
\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\small\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}
```